# Smoother not working with NavThroughPoses (ros2 humble)

Tags: navigation, ros-humble, path-planning, nav2

I have the following behavior tree:

```
<!--
  This Behavior Tree replans the global path periodically at 0.8 Hz through an array of poses continuously
   and it also has recovery actions specific to planning / control as well as general system issues.
-->
<root main_tree_to_execute="MainTree">
  <BehaviorTree ID="MainTree">

    <RecoveryNode number_of_retries="6" name="NavigateRecovery">
      <PipelineSequence name="NavigateWithReplanning">
        <RateController hz="0.8">
          <RecoveryNode number_of_retries="1" name="ComputePathThroughPoses">
            <ReactiveSequence>
              <RemovePassedGoals input_goals="{goals}" output_goals="{goals}" radius="0.7"/>
              <Sequence>
                <ComputePathThroughPoses goals="{goals}" path="{path}" planner_id="GridBased"/>
                <SmoothPath unsmoothed_path="{path}" smoothed_path="{path}"/>
              </Sequence>
            </ReactiveSequence>
            <ClearEntireCostmap name="ClearGlobalCostmap-Context" service_name="global_costmap/clear_entirely_global_costmap"/>
          </RecoveryNode>
        </RateController>
        <RecoveryNode number_of_retries="1" name="FollowPath">
          <FollowPath path="{path}" controller_id="FollowPath"/>
          <ClearEntireCostmap name="ClearLocalCostmap-Context" service_name="local_costmap/clear_entirely_local_costmap"/>
        </RecoveryNode>
      </PipelineSequence>

      <!-- Recovery subtree -->
      <ReactiveFallback name="RecoveryFallback">
        <GoalUpdated/>
        <RoundRobin name="RecoveryActions">
          <Sequence name="ClearingActions">
            <ClearEntireCostmap name="ClearLocalCostmap-Subtree" service_name="local_costmap/clear_entirely_local_costmap"/>
            <ClearEntireCostmap name="ClearGlobalCostmap-Subtree" service_name="global_costmap/clear_entirely_global_costmap"/>
          </Sequence>
          <Spin spin_dist="0.57"/>
          <Wait wait_duration="5"/>
          <BackUp backup_dist="0.30" backup_speed="0.05"/>
        </RoundRobin>
      </ReactiveFallback>
    </RecoveryNode>
  </BehaviorTree>
</root>
```

Which is basically the `navigate_through_poses_w_replanning_and_recovery` behavior tree with 3 lines of code added:

```
              <Sequence>
                <ComputePathThroughPoses goals="{goals}" path="{path}" planner_id="GridBased"/>
                <SmoothPath unsmoothed_path="{path}" smoothed_path="{path}"/>
              </Sequence>
```

I observe a weird behavior in case the smoother server fails at some point:

[image: Smoother server fails]

At that point the whole system seems like it is stuck. The robot keeps following the path with the **local controller** but the **global planner** does not create a new plan. We also do **NOT** go into the recovery subtree for a long time (until it is called because our robot is not making progress for 30 seconds).

My explanation would be that when the smoother server fails, it does **NOT** return a status of `FAILURE` but a status of `RUNNING` (the fact that the `RecoveryNode` does not call `<ClearEntireCostmap name="ClearGlobalCostmap-Context" service_name="global_costmap/clear_entirely_global_costmap"/>` also indicates that smoother is still `RUNNING` instead of `FAILURE`. `FollowPath` is in the `Pipeline Sequence` and therefore is still being called (that's why the robot is still moving). The `Recovery subtree` is never called as `FAILURE` was not returned by anything. The robot eventually stops moving of course and stays still for the rest of time.

I also noticed that at least in `ROS2 humble` the `smooth_path_action.cpp` does not do anything in case the smoother action firstly fails and and then gets stuck in `RUNNING`. Through the behavior tree I tried to set timers that would force the `SmoothPath` to return `FAILURE` but that did not work. Any ideas on how to solve this?

**Note**: This happens even when I set:
`<SmoothPath unsmoothed_path="{path}" />`
and we therefore do not smooth the path anymore

**Note 2**: In ROS2 humble `WouldASmootherRecoveryHelp` does not work (for me). I noticed that in `github` there are some differences in the main branch and the humble branch regarding the number of files that contain the `WouldASmootherRecoveryHelp` keyword.